# android : issue getting file path on Lollipop

Tags: android

So, I have following code to pick file:

```
public void getFile() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException exp) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No File (Manager / Explorer)etc Found In Your Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

This is how I implemented `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String srcFile = data.getData().getPath();
                Log.i("Path: ", srcFile);
                // rest of the code to upload file to server
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**Problem is:**

I am getting path on Jellybean(Android 4.1.2) as below:

> /sdcard/Download/93e8c6b0c589feed4037375aecaf4a1e.txt

But when I try to get path in Lollipop I get something like:

> /document/B0EC-6E35:TestWordDoc.doc

Goal is to pick any file and upload it to server. I am able to do my task on Jellybean device but not on Lollipop. Did anyone face issue like this ? If so, Please help me.. It got two days of mine, and I am still no where..

Comment: With KitKat and Above, you will always get content Stream, that why you are getting path like this.

Comment: @dex can you suggest me some workaround ?

Comment: you need to make a copy out of content stream, that will work in all cases, if you have read/Write then you can directly work on that content stream.